# Font awesome youtube not working on my site

Tags: jquery, css, youtube, font-awesome

I have font awesome properly loaded and working, all the other icons of the widget are working, except for youtube. I don't have adblock.

My code is:

```
<div class="social">
  <a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/LucreBem/135826256498651" class="link facebook" target="_parent"><span class="icon-facebook-sign"></span></a>

  <a rel="nofollow" href="https://twitter.com/lucrebem" class="link twitter" target="_parent"><span class="icon-twitter-sign"></span></a>

  <a rel="nofollow" href="https://plus.google.com/+LucreBem" class="link google-plus" target="_parent"><span class="icon-google-plus-sign"></span></a>


  <a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.youtube.com/user/lucrebem" class="link youtube" target="_parent"><span class="icon-youtube-sign"></span></a>


  <a rel="nofollow" href="https://br.linkedin.com/pub/lucre-bem/60/4aa/808" class="link linkedin" target="_parent"><span class="icon-linkedin-sign"></span></a>
</div>
```

You can check it here: http://lucrebem.com.br/blog/emponline/90-o-hotmart-e-a-pirataria-uma-tragica-estoria-de-amor-em-3-atos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this unicode style:

```
<span class="icon-foo" style="
    font-family: FontAwesome;
">&#xf16a;</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://lucrebem.com.br/templates/rt_afterburner2/css-compiled/master-32b1b3a67a6e81d35c7c0b92f647986e.css

The stylesheet where the font icons are referenced, does not include any '.icon-youtube-sign'.

Comment: Just go there and check now what's in the place of youtube.

Comment: @MatheusLopes you now have 2 x youtube icons

Comment: Yeep, two different youtube icons, just take a look. One for each youtube channel :D